# princiapal.getName() returns ID instead of name for facebook

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, spring-boot, single-sign-on, spring-security-oauth2

I have my custom auth server implemented using spring-security-oauth along with several client applications for Single Sign On, I have the option of facebook and google login.

Now on my client application when I have this controller:

```
    @RequestMapping({ "/user", "/me" })
public Principal user(Principal principal) {
    return principal;
}
```

For google It works fine and returns name but for facebook it returns a unique ID. I've tried many ways but i am not able to get name from this principal object. can someone please help?

This is my short cutted facebook config:

```
accessTokenUri: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
userAuthorizationUri: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth
tokenName: oauth_token
authenticationScheme: query
clientAuthenticationScheme: form
userInfoUri: https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,email
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `f_name` instead of `name` for **Facebook Graph API**

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got the work around for it:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/user", "/me"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Map<String, String> user(Principal principal) {
    Map<String, Object> details = (Map<String, Object>) ((OAuth2Authentication) principal).getUserAuthentication().getDetails();
    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map.put("name", (String) details.get("name"));
    map.put("email", (String) details.get("email"));
    return map;
}
```